# Бот не работает и выдает ошибку((

Tags: python

Написал бота, который является модератором! Он призапуске должен повторять мое сообщение(я сейчас про личные сообщения с ним говорю)!

```
import logging
import telebot
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor,types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("5065462880:AAFS1Op-hjhdHpCe6Ey2_yowvc7eODs_Cq4")
dp=Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message:types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

if _name_=="_main_":
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=False)
```

А также мне питон выдает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/Desktop/Modertor/moderator.py", line 8, in <module>
    dp=Dispatcher(bot)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 51, in __init__
    raise TypeError(f"Argument 'bot' must be an instance of Bot, not '{type(bot).__name__}'")
TypeError: Argument 'bot' must be an instance of Bot, not 'TeleBot'
```

Comment: Ну потому что вы в Dispatcher от aiogram передаете экземпляр из телебота.. Может стоит сначала что-то попроще попробовать сделать?

Comment: а что нельзя так делать? Расскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно

Comment: @ВячеславГвоздиков для начала надо определиться какую библиотеку использовать, советую aiogram, в интернете куча примеров, как это сделать

Comment: так я уже скачал бибилиотеку aiogram в cmd

Answer (score 1):

Все же рекомендую сначала уже изучить сам Python, а потом уже делать ботов.
Документация по aiogram - https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor


bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nНапиши мне что-нибудь!")


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: и да! Вы пишите bot = Bot(token='token'). А это означает, что  у меня должен быть другой файл с токеном. но зачем мне его создавать, если можно сделать через телебот, я уже так сделал далеко не одного бота

Comment: @ВячеславГвоздиков и что? Какой файл с токеном? О чём вы? Вместо `'token'` надо указать свой токен и всё будет работать, телебот и аиограм разные библиотеки, они не совместимы друг с другом, очень жаль Ваших ботов

Comment: что касается библиотеки aiogram, то ее я использую в первый раз, поэтому такая неурядица